# iOS 10 Callkit : How to notify OS that my VOIP application supports Callkit on fresh installation of my app

Tags: ios10, callkit

I want to show my VOIP app in suggestion from native contacts when user long press the call button.

Currently i am informing to OS about callkit while placing/receiving the calls.

But i want to inform OS about callkit in my app as the app installed first time like whatsapp is doing.

Can anyone suggest me how can i do that ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure the provider delegate, you must configure supported handle types with `CXHandleTypePhoneNumber`.

But for notify to system, you need start app once at least (and you must be sure that provider delegate is init to notify system), it isn't enough with install.